# swift 4 Empty UITableView before UIRefeshControl

Tags: swift, tableview, swift4

Good day, guys!
I have a little problem with updating data.
I'm getting information from backend with JSON-RPC and populating my table view cells.
I implemented UIRefreshContol to my TableView, so now when I pull to refresh it gives me the new information on top of old one.
So I have a list of products and when I add some products and refresh tableView to get updated information, tableView gives me old info AND new one on top of the old one
Are there any ways to empty table before I will get updated information from JSON?

// That's my JSON

```
func getJSONresponse() {
    getResponse(o_method: "search_read", o_model: "res.users", o_domain:[["id", "=", jkID]], o_fields: ["name","partner_id"]) { (result) -> () in
        //print(result)
        if result != JSON.null {
            let partner_id = result[0]["partner_id"][0].int!
            getResponse(o_method: "search_read", o_model: "res.partner", o_domain: [["id", "=", partner_id]], o_fields: ["name", "kato"], completion: { (result)->() in
                //print(result)
                let id = result[0]["kato"][0].int!
                katoID = id
                print("adiasodjasoid",katoID)
                getResponse(o_method: "search_read", o_model: "property.building", o_domain: [], o_fields: ["name","kato_area"], completion: { (result)->() in

                    result.forEach({ (temp) in

                        var area:String = "", name:String = "", totID: Int = 0

                        if (temp.1["kato_area"].string != nil) {
                            area = temp.1["kato_area"].string!
                        }
                        if (temp.1["name"].string != nil) {
                            name = temp.1["name"].string!
                        }
                        if (temp.1["id"].int != nil) {
                            totID = temp.1["id"].int!
                        }

                        let newModel = resUser(area: area, name: name, id: totID)
                        self.data.append(newModel)
                    })
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    //                        print(self.data)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

That's my Pull to refresh Function

```
@objc func refreshData() {

    tableView.reloadData()
    getJSONresponse()
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, what you have tried so far. Quick approach could be empty the array in refresh-control's action method.

Comment: Empty the datasource and then enter new data to the data source  and then reload the table.

Comment: I have updated code, please, check it out

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked for me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you will have to bind the UITableView with to an array, some may also refer to it to as datasource.

So basically heres the flow:

1) Create a mutable array/datasource (This will hold all the JSON).

2) Correspond UITableView number of rows method to return the count this array/datasource.

3) When you press the refresh. remove all the contents of the array/datasource (removeAll)

4) Once you receive the response from backend, add them to the array/datasource and call reloadData on UITableView object.

Hope That Helps. Code and Prosper!!

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot!

Comment: No worries!! Happy to help. 

If this answer helped you achieve what you were trying to achieve. Then please do mark it as correct so that it helps others in future

Answer (score 1):

Please bind `UITableView` with an `Array`. Then update this `Array` first from the data that you are getting from JSON (Empty it and put in the new data), and then call `UITableView` reload.

Comment: Should I pass empty data instead of new one? Could you please help me with example how to do it?

Comment: Thank you so much, I could do it :)

Comment: @АкарысТурганбекулы - first empty it, then put all new data in it in your completion: block.